# nth-child not working properly, sometimes count is wrong

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have problem with :nth-child pseudoclass. As in the topic, in some cases it counts wrong or it's something with the media queries.
I want my modal to stick to the left side and I can't give it position absolute...
Code below is a part of the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/WThuW/3/)

```
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 599px) {
.box {
    width: 33.333333333331%;
}
.content .box:nth-child(2) .all-box-info,
.content .box:nth-child(2n+3) .all-box-info {
    margin-left: -100%;
}
.content .box:nth-child(3) .all-box-info,
.content .box:nth-child(3n+3) .all-box-info {
    margin-left: -200%;
}
.content .box:nth-child(10) .all-box-info {
    margin-left: 0;
}
}
```

Check the JSFiffle > http://jsfiddle.net/WThuW/2/

Note that there are media queries! When 2 boxes in row everything is ok. With 3 and more there is a problem in at least one of the modals.

Hope somebody know what to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

replace
`.content .box:nth-child(2n+3) .all-box-info {`
with:
`.content .box:nth-child(3n+2) .all-box-info {`

Comment: O M G... this is what I wanted to avoid. Haha! My bad!
Mistake in simple equation. SRSLY?! 

THANK YOU 4 help!